# Creating a difference matrix comparing differences between all rows in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, networkx, igraph

I have a dataframe with two columns: the first is the name of US politicians (`bioname`). The second column is their D-W ideological score (`dw1`). I want to create a network in which the `bioname` are nodes/vertices, while edges/ties are weighted as the difference between the two politicians' `dw1` scores. For example, I would want the edge weight between Trump and Biden to be .3615 (.7015 - .34) and .022 (.7015 - .6795) between Trump and Rogers, and so on for EVERY POSSIBLE PAIR of subjects in the dataset.

How can I reformat my data to compute these differences for all politicians in the dataset?

| bioname | dw1 |
| --- | --- |
| Trump | 0.7015 |
| Biden | 0.3400 |
| Rogers | 0.6795 |
| Sewell | 0.3035 |
| Brooks | 0.8255 |

Comment: Please share you sample data as text, not a picture.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I updated it to text. Does it look correct now?

Comment: I can copy/paste it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dist` should also work

```
out <- with(df, as.matrix(dist(setNames(dw1, bioname))))
```

-output

```
> out
        Trump  Biden Rogers Sewell Brooks
Trump  0.0000 0.3615 0.0220 0.3980 0.1240
Biden  0.3615 0.0000 0.3395 0.0365 0.4855
Rogers 0.0220 0.3395 0.0000 0.3760 0.1460
Sewell 0.3980 0.0365 0.3760 0.0000 0.5220
Brooks 0.1240 0.4855 0.1460 0.5220 0.0000
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a named vector and use `outer` to build a matrix of differences. Calling your data frame `df`:

```
named_vec = setNames(df$dw1, nm = df$bioname)
outer(named_vec, named_vec, FUN = "-")
#          Trump   Biden  Rogers Sewell  Brooks
# Trump   0.0000  0.3615  0.0220 0.3980 -0.1240
# Biden  -0.3615  0.0000 -0.3395 0.0365 -0.4855
# Rogers -0.0220  0.3395  0.0000 0.3760 -0.1460
# Sewell -0.3980 -0.0365 -0.3760 0.0000 -0.5220
# Brooks  0.1240  0.4855  0.1460 0.5220  0.0000
```

---

Using this data

```
df = read.table(text = 'bioname dw1
Trump   0.7015
Biden   0.3400
Rogers  0.6795
Sewell  0.3035
Brooks  0.8255', header = T)
```